# Colic has worsened while traveling

Tags: infant, crying, travel, colic, gas

We have a 4.5mo old and have taken her on her first "family vacation."  We're on day six of a 14 day trip involving about 5hrs of airplane travel (which she handled very well) but she has has awful gas pains since arriving.  Every night involves at least one shrieking session lasting 30-60mins with smaller bouts throughout the day spaced by about 1.5-2.0hrs.

She has no problems at home. Food sources have not changed (including mother's diet).  The only real difference between our vacation destination and home is the humidity and heat.  It's very humid and cool (~80°F) at the destination and very dry and very hot (~110°-115°F) at home.

We use gripe water as needed and probiotics daily.

What's the deal?

Comment: Is her stools regular and liquidy, typical for a baby (assuming she is not having solid food yet). I would think about constipation and getting enough fluids in hot areas, but I don't think that part would impact baby before weaning much?

Comment: Yes.  Everything else seems normal.

Comment: Give baby Domstal Oral Drops 5 drops. It is really helpful for my baby.

Comment: Probably just stress from the new environment — cuddle her, reassure her, it'll pass.

Comment: It was a non-issue the moment we got home.  Strange.

Answer (score 1):

Before you follow any advice you find here or elsewhere on the web, you really should call your pediatrician, who is the expert you pay for helping in these types of situations. If you are a new parent, you may not realize that most pediatricians' office have nurses or medical assistants who take these types of phone calls. These professionals can give you advice on over the counter remedies, as well as give you advice on when it is time to seek help from a practitioner. With five kids, I think we know the doctor's medical assistant better than we know the doctor herself.

Another good source of advice in a situation like this is to ask a pharmacist, who is an expert in both prescription and, more importantly in this case, over the counter remedies. I think we often don't give pharmacists the credit they deserve.

The Mayo Clinic has a page of [advice on colic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/colic/basics/lifestyle-home-remedies/con-20019091); you might find that page useful.

Finally, sometimes there is nothing you can do to help. But I can promise you this: it does get better. With our first kid, we sat up for many hours every night watching movies (with the subtitles on, because we couldn't hear the movie over the crying), holding, rocking, and trying to comfort a very fussy, colicky baby, and eventually he grew out of it. That was a really good time for us to have a Netflix subscription. :)

Hang in there! It's hard, but you can do it.

Comment: Back home now and zero crying.  Must have been the humidity, new smells, or some other "different thing" she didn't like.